# Toolbar title is displaying out of place

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using Collapsing toolbar in coordinator layout to achieve the following result. However the problem is when the Collapsing toolbar collapses, the title of the toolbar doesn't show in it proper place for some reason. I couldn't figure out what might be causing this weird issue. How can I fix this?

**Support design library:** version: *25.1.0*

**Min SDK:** 19

**Target SDK:** 25

**Compile SDK:** 25

Following is the code for the fragment shown in the pictures below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/collapsing_toolbar_title_margin_end"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/collapsing_toolbar_title_margin_start"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarTextAppearance"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ashiyana_cover"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_circle_progress_bar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_circle_progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:mlpb_progress_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <!-- RECYCLER VIEW FOR DISPLAYING COMICS CARD GRID-->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/list_comics"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_beAHost"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_frag_main_screen"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_button_frag_main_screen"
                android:text="Be A Host"
                tools:text="Be A Host"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_main_screen">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_heading"
                    android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"
                    android:text="@string/string_search"
                    tools:text="Search"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_room"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_button_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_button_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_frag_main_screen"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_button_frag_main_screen"
                    android:text="@string/string_room"
                    tools:text="Room"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_hostel"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_button_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_button_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_frag_main_screen"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_button_frag_main_screen"
                    android:text="@string/string_hostel"
                    tools:text="Hostel"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_apartment"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_button_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_button_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_frag_main_screen"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_search_layout_frag_main_screen"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_button_frag_main_screen"
                    android:text="@string/string_apartment"
                    tools:text="Apartment"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: where do you set the title text?

Comment: I'm setting it in onCreateView of the fragment

Comment: Can you show that code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because in your activity, you forgot to put:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //or whatever your toolbar id is 
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```